# right-to-left (RTL) in flutter

Tags: layout, flutter, right-to-left, direction

I was using Flutter more than a week, and wanted to create an Arabic (right-to-left) app.

I was reading [Internationalizing Flutter Apps](https://flutter.io/tutorials/internationalization/), but it didn't mention how to set the layout direction.

So, how to show right-to-left (RTL) layout in Flutter?

Comment: If you just need to set the text direction set the `textDirection` property to TextDirection.rtl your TextField or Text widget.

Comment: How to restrict a widget to change its children's alignment when the locale is changed?
Could you please solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65180615/restrict-a-widget-to-change-its-childrens-alignment-when-locale-is-changed-flut

Answer (score 203, accepted):

you have two choices :

**1. force a locale ( and direction ) on all devices**

-- ***method 1:*** with localization

add `flutter_localizations` package to your `pubspec.yml`

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
```

then

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

MaterialApp(
  localizationsDelegates: [
    GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
  supportedLocales: [
    Locale("fa", "IR"), // OR Locale('ar', 'AE') OR Other RTL locales
  ],
  locale: Locale("fa", "IR") // OR Locale('ar', 'AE') OR Other RTL locales,
  .
  .
  .
);
```

-- ***method 2:*** without localization

```dart
MaterialApp(
  .
  .
  .
  builder: (context, child) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: child,
    );
  },
  .
  .
  .
);
```

**2. set layout direction according to device locale
( if user phone locale is a `RTL` language and exist in `supportedLocales`, your app run in `RTL` mode, otherwise your app is `LTR` )**

add `flutter_localizations` package to your `pubspec.yml`

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
```

then

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

MaterialApp(
  localizationsDelegates: [
    GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
  supportedLocales: [
    Locale("en", "US"),
    Locale("fa", "IR"), // OR Locale('ar', 'AE') OR Other RTL locales
  ],
  .
  .
  .
);
```

**note** : rtl languages in flutter are:

```dart
[
  'ar', // Arabic
  'fa', // Farsi
  'he', // Hebrew
  'ps', // Pashto
  'ur', // Urdu
];
```

Comment: _rtlLanguages is not use

Comment: The getter 'rtl' isn't defined for the type 'TextDirection'.

Comment: @BhargavSejpal if you imported `intl`package, you must import intl with name : `import 'package:intl/intl.dart' as intl`

Comment: @mohammad Hi , please answer my question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68528499

Comment: @DJafari Hi, please answer my question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68528499

Comment: @DJafari is there any way of obtaining or changing the current ``textDirection`` ?

Comment: @jksevend please ask your question in another question and insert link here

Comment: is it possible to RTL a `MaterialBanner` ? i asked this Question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74020451/flutter-can-materialbanner-have-rtl-direction

Answer (score 52):

The best and shortest way to **set `RTL` configuration for the entire app**.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Directionality( // add this
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl, // set this property 
        child: HomePage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: error: The argument type 'TextDirection (where TextDirection is defined in D:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\intl-0.15.8\lib\src\intl\bidi_utils.dart)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TextDirection (where TextDirection is defined in D:\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\ui\text.dart)'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [zapit] lib\main.dart:186)

Comment: @EliaWeiss Make sure you don't import any other conflicting package, this is the one you should be using import `package:flutter/material.dart`;

Comment: How to set dynamic when button click from any page? As user wants to change RTL to LTR then how to do?

Comment: this answer is incorect, because this make only home page rtl, other pages must wrap with `Directionality` too, check my second method of choise 1

Comment: @DJafari This will make all pages rtl not just the `HomePage`. If you navigate to other pages from your `HomePage`, you'll see this in effect.

Answer (score 44):

You need to create a [Builder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html) and pass it the layout direction using `TextDirection.rtl`

```dart
new MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter RTL',
          color: Colors.grey,
          builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
              return new Directionality(
                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                child: new Builder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return new MediaQuery(
                      data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
                            textScaleFactor: 1.0,
                          ),
                      child: child,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          .
          .
          .
        );
```

Comment: Although it's working, I don't like this answer. You have provided no explanation about how it works or how doing this affects other layouting calculations and etc.

Comment: Why do you need to override the text scale factor?

Answer (score 11):

If you need to display text in reverse direction then just set it's `textDirection` property to `TextDirection.rtl`.

Example code for TextField widget,

```
TextField(
  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Enter Pashto Name",
  ),
),
```

Example code for Text widget,

```
    Text(
      "This text is in the other direction!"
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
    ),
```

Comment: You can even use it for Text widget

Comment: best Answer , Worked for me shortcut

Answer (score 2):

Just append this to your material app:

```
 builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
              return new Directionality(
                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                child: new Builder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return new MediaQuery(
                      data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
                            textScaleFactor: 1.0,
                          ),
                      child: child,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use   flutter_localizations:
sdk: flutter

add these line to change your app direction

```
 supportedLocales: [
    Locale("fa", "IR"), 
    Locale("en", 'US'),
  ],
  locale: Locale("fa", "IR")  // this is important line if not add this Apps will not change direction
```

Answer (score 1):

`GetMaterialApp( textDirection: TextDirection.rtl, home: SignUpScreen() // const HomeExpert() );`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This is only for `Get` StateManager , what about provider or generic?