# How can i change direction in show case view?

Tags: flutter, dart

i use show case view package and i want to have rtl direction ,
how can i do this ?[image]

```
                     Showcase(
                      showArrow: false,
                      key: _twoCaseShow,
                      disableAnimation: true,
                      description: 'مشاهده کلیه درخواست های شما',
                      child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: 
                              Icon(
                                FontAwesomeIcons.list,
                                color: ColorsBase.blue,
                              ),                               
                            ],
                          )),
                         )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Showcaseview official repository](https://github.com/simformsolutions/flutter_showcaseview/blob/4f542351e91c15418f36677c0f8f65edfb50fa2b/lib/tooltip_widget.dart#L211), we can see that the description property is being used as follows:

```
Text(
                                      description,
                                      style: descTextStyle ??
                                          Theme.of(context)
                                              .textTheme
                                              .subtitle
                                              .merge(TextStyle(color: textColor)),
                                    )
```

This means you can change this line of the package to include the direction property:

```
Text(
                                      description,
                                      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                      style: descTextStyle ??
                                          Theme.of(context)
                                              .textTheme
                                              .subtitle
                                              .merge(TextStyle(color: textColor)),
                                    )
```

However, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57863925/10746978) suggests, other solution is to use the [Directionality class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Directionality-class.html) to change the directionality of the text widget from outside of it:

```
Directionality(
 textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
 child: Showcase(
                      showArrow: false,
                      key: _twoCaseShow,
                      disableAnimation: true,
                      description: 'مشاهده کلیه درخواست های شما',
                      child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: 
                              Icon(
                                FontAwesomeIcons.list,
                                color: ColorsBase.blue,
                              ),                               
                            ],
                          )),
                         ),
    )
```