# How to use Align or Positioned in Stack , Taking into account the direction of the language

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In my case, I have a **Stack** containing  **Icon** and  **Card**

I want the icon to appear in the right corner in case **LTR** and in the left corner in case **RTL**

I have the following code:

```
Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 4,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, right: 8, left: 8),
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('text 1'),
                  Text('text 2'),
                  Text('text 3'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 10,
          left: 10,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.ac_unit,
            size: 50,
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
```

The result in **RTL** mode is :
[image]

The result in **LTR** mode is :
[image]

**How can I fix this**

Comment: If you want it on the right, then instead of left in the positioned put right:10

Comment: I want it when the language changes, its place changes automatically, like the three texts

Comment: Add a conditional for displaying the Positioned Widget. Like if(RTL) Positioned(right:10)
If you get what I mean

Comment: This answer seems to address your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/50535186/442553

Comment: If I used a Row Widget, the icon would change position automatically like the three Texts, but here the situation is a little different

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this

```
  Positioned.directional(textDirection:Directionality.of(context) ,
    top: 10,
    end:  10,
    child: Icon(
      Icons.ac_unit,
      size: 50,
    ),
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for `Directionality.of(context)`

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE**

Put the icon inside a Container with maxWidth and set the alignment like below

```
alignment: isRTL? Alignment.centerLeft: Alignment.centerRight;
```

set the alignment property of Stack like this.

when the Language is changed to RTL just call

```
setState((){
 isRTL = true;
})
```

in a stateful widget.

vice versa if you want to change it to LTR

Comment: It is a solution, but not the best

Comment: best answer needs a best question, try to update your question regarding what exactly you want, steps to be involved.

Comment: I apologize, I think the question is clear. Take a look at the question's comments

Comment: have you looked into Directionality widget?