# How to define RTL for some part, not all part?

Tags: flutter, dart, design-patterns

I want to create an application that the intro app of my app to be LTR and other parts to be RTL. I found some code for RTL:

```
  localizationsDelegates: [
    GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
  supportedLocales: [
    Locale("fa", "IR"), // OR Locale('ar', 'AE') OR Other RTL locales
  ],
  locale: Locale("fa", "IR")
```

But it is used for all parts, not some parts, please help me.
I used this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/intro_slider) for my app intro

Comment: this might answer your question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54689825/6413387

Comment: It doesn't work for me, thanks.