# How to build list of widgets right to left in Flutter gridview.count for arabic layout

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to show list of widgets, building from right to left.

[You can see in this picture i want to show arabic alphabets... widgets should be start from right to left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mg1Gh.jpg)

```
SliverGrid.count(
        crossAxisCount: 5,
        mainAxisSpacing: 1,
        crossAxisSpacing: 1,
        children: listLessonOne,
      ),
```

one of the widget from List listLessonOne

```
CustomWordCard(
word: 'ا',
subWord: 'الف',
```

),

Comment: Implement arabic localisation for your app and set locale to arabic, you will get what you need out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            child : yourchild)
```

but below answer is better ...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54689825/6813907

Comment: this is just for text not working on widgets