# flutter how to Create right to left (rtl) App

Tags: flutter, localization, right-to-left, flutter-getx

I start an App in Flutter with GetX . I want to Create a rtl App and I used flutter_localizations package as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54689825/1786401) .

This is my main() code

```
void main() => runApp(
      GetMaterialApp(
        localizationsDelegates: [
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: [
          Locale('fa', 'IR'),
        ],
        locale: Locale('fa', 'IR'),
        home: HomeScreen(),
      ),
    );
```

and this is my HomeScreen Code

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Text(
          "Some Text",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

and as you see in this picture , debug banner has gone to left side but text steel is in left

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your app is rtl correctly, your problem is current body widget, test this as body widget :

```dart
body: SafeArea(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    children: [
      Text("Some Text"),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thank you a lot but why it does not work with column , only works with row ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `textDirection` property and set it to `TextDirection.rtl`

**Local TextDirection**

```
Text(
  "Some Text",
  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
),
```

---

**Global TextDirection**

```
MaterialApp(
      home: Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl, 
        child: UserDetailsScreen(),
      ),
    ),
```

**Complete Example:**

```
void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: Directionality(
            // add this
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            child: HomeScreen()),
      ),
    );

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Text(
          "ہائے میں فلاں دنیا ہوں !!! امید ہے کہ آپ اچھا کر رہے ہیں۔ کوڈنگ مبارک ہو :)",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi, I want to convert whole my App to rtl not some of text or images

Comment: Thank you but noting happened :-(

Comment: close application and re-run again this should work

Comment: I did . But nothing changed :-(

Comment: I have updated my flutter version this morning . Is it depend ?

Comment: check edited answer, added complete example

Comment: Thank you alot but this code works if text is in rtl language only

Comment: try english with long text

Answer (score 1):

The App is already rtl. it is just that the widget under the safeArea puts the widget to the left with minimum size, *I dont' know why this happens* try wrapping your text widget with a row or with a container and give it a width then you can see that the default is now to the right not left.

[image]

Comment: Thank you alot but I dont want to set TextAlign for every widgets

Comment: you don't need to, the default is now set to right, it will be the same thing without the textAlign property (I forgot to delete the line).