# how to achive justify-center with rich text in flutter

Tags: flutter, center, text-align, justify

Align property in rich text widget have right,left,center and justify,

when using center it gave me centered text without justifying it and when using justify it gave me ltr justify.

**this code:**

```
RichText(
      textAlign:TextAlign.center,
      text:TextSpan(
        children:[
          TextSpan(text: 'مَثَلُهُمْ كَمَثَلِ ٱلَّذِى ٱسْتَوْقَدَ نَارًا فَلَمَّآ أَضَآءَتْ مَا حَوْلَهُۥ ذَهَبَ ٱللَّهُ بِنُورِهِمْ وَتَرَكَهُمْ فِى ظُلُمَٰتٍۢ لَّا يُبْصِرُونَ, صُمٌّۢ بُكْمٌ عُمْىٌ فَهُمْ لَا يَرْجِعُونَ, أَوْ كَصَيِّبٍۢ مِّنَ ٱلسَّمَآءِ فِيهِ ظُلُمَٰتٌ وَرَعْدٌ وَبَرْقٌ يَجْعَلُونَ أَصَٰبِعَهُمْ فِىٓ ءَاذَانِهِم مِّنَ ٱلصَّوَٰعِقِ حَذَرَ ٱلْمَوْتِ ۚ وَٱللَّهُ مُحِيطٌۢ بِٱلْكَٰفِرِينَ'),
          TextSpan(text:'وَإِن كُنتُمْ فِى رَيْبٍۢ مِّمَّا نَزَّلْنَا عَلَىٰ عَبْدِنَا فَأْتُواْ بِسُورَةٍۢ مِّن مِّثْلِهِۦ وَٱدْعُواْ شُهَدَآءَكُم مِّن دُونِ ٱللَّهِ إِن كُنتُمْ صَٰدِقِينَ, فَإِن لَّمْ تَفْعَلُواْ وَلَن تَفْعَلُواْ فَٱتَّقُواْ ٱلنَّارَ ٱلَّتِى وَقُودُهَا ٱلنَّاسُ وَٱلْحِجَارَةُ ۖ أُعِدَّتْ لِلْكَٰفِرِينَ')
    ]))
```

**gave this:**
[image]

**and this code:**

```
RichText(
      textAlign:TextAlign.justify,
      text:TextSpan(
        children:[
          TextSpan(text: 'مَثَلُهُمْ كَمَثَلِ ٱلَّذِى ٱسْتَوْقَدَ نَارًا فَلَمَّآ أَضَآءَتْ مَا حَوْلَهُۥ ذَهَبَ ٱللَّهُ بِنُورِهِمْ وَتَرَكَهُمْ فِى ظُلُمَٰتٍۢ لَّا يُبْصِرُونَ, صُمٌّۢ بُكْمٌ عُمْىٌ فَهُمْ لَا يَرْجِعُونَ, أَوْ كَصَيِّبٍۢ مِّنَ ٱلسَّمَآءِ فِيهِ ظُلُمَٰتٌ وَرَعْدٌ وَبَرْقٌ يَجْعَلُونَ أَصَٰبِعَهُمْ فِىٓ ءَاذَانِهِم مِّنَ ٱلصَّوَٰعِقِ حَذَرَ ٱلْمَوْتِ ۚ وَٱللَّهُ مُحِيطٌۢ بِٱلْكَٰفِرِينَ'),
          TextSpan(text:'وَإِن كُنتُمْ فِى رَيْبٍۢ مِّمَّا نَزَّلْنَا عَلَىٰ عَبْدِنَا فَأْتُواْ بِسُورَةٍۢ مِّن مِّثْلِهِۦ وَٱدْعُواْ شُهَدَآءَكُم مِّن دُونِ ٱللَّهِ إِن كُنتُمْ صَٰدِقِينَ, فَإِن لَّمْ تَفْعَلُواْ وَلَن تَفْعَلُواْ فَٱتَّقُواْ ٱلنَّارَ ٱلَّتِى وَقُودُهَا ٱلنَّاسُ وَٱلْحِجَارَةُ ۖ أُعِدَّتْ لِلْكَٰفِرِينَ')
    ]))
```

**gave this:**
[image]

how can i make the align of the text is both, justify and center especially with arabic text like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `softWrap` & `textAlign` property of `RichText` widget to center align and wrap the content text accordingly.

example:

```
RichText(
      softWrap:true,
      textAlign:TextAlign.center,
      text:TextSpan(
        style:TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),
        children:[
          TextSpan(text: 'كن لا بد أن أوضح لك أن كل هذه الأفكار المغلوطة حول استنكار'),
          TextSpan(text:' الحصول على ميزة أو فائدة؟ ولكن من لديه الحق أن ينتقد شخص ما أراد أن يشعر بالسعادة التي لا تشوبها عواقب أليمة ')
    ]))
```

ouput:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding answer what you want to do in flutter, code example is below.

```
Text('my String', textAlign: TextAlign.justify)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help.

Comment: you check it with my code this link -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50535185/right-to-left-rtl-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might need to set the `textDirection` property of your `RichText` widget:

```dart
RichText(
    textAlign:TextAlign.justify,
    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl //<-- Add this
    text:TextSpan(
      children:[
        TextSpan(text: 'مَثَلُهُمْ كَمَثَلِ ٱلَّذِى ٱسْتَوْقَدَ نَارًا فَلَمَّآ أَضَآءَتْ مَا حَوْلَهُۥ ذَهَبَ ٱللَّهُ بِنُورِهِمْ وَتَرَكَهُمْ فِى ظُلُمَٰتٍۢ لَّا يُبْصِرُونَ, صُمٌّۢ بُكْمٌ عُمْىٌ فَهُمْ لَا يَرْجِعُونَ, أَوْ كَصَيِّبٍۢ مِّنَ ٱلسَّمَآءِ فِيهِ ظُلُمَٰتٌ وَرَعْدٌ وَبَرْقٌ يَجْعَلُونَ أَصَٰبِعَهُمْ فِىٓ ءَاذَانِهِم مِّنَ ٱلصَّوَٰعِقِ حَذَرَ ٱلْمَوْتِ ۚ وَٱللَّهُ مُحِيطٌۢ بِٱلْكَٰفِرِينَ'),
        TextSpan(text:'وَإِن كُنتُمْ فِى رَيْبٍۢ مِّمَّا نَزَّلْنَا عَلَىٰ عَبْدِنَا فَأْتُواْ بِسُورَةٍۢ مِّن مِّثْلِهِۦ وَٱدْعُواْ شُهَدَآءَكُم مِّن دُونِ ٱللَّهِ إِن كُنتُمْ صَٰدِقِينَ, فَإِن لَّمْ تَفْعَلُواْ وَلَن تَفْعَلُواْ فَٱتَّقُواْ ٱلنَّارَ ٱلَّتِى وَقُودُهَا ٱلنَّاسُ وَٱلْحِجَارَةُ ۖ أُعِدَّتْ لِلْكَٰفِرِينَ')
    ],
  ),
)
```