# How to change Expansion Tile Direction in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using endDrawer and inside it I used Expansion Tile,But My Laguage is persian and it's Direction is rtl.
Expantion Tile's deafualt Direction is ltr but I want to be rtl

Comment: Can you add a couple of screenshots to illustrate the issue? I think I understand you, but there are decorators on the collapsed Expansion Tile view and I think you need to also consider those.

Comment: Is this answer helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50535185/right-to-left-rtl-in-flutter Or this article? https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization

Answer (score 0):

You must wrap ExpansionTile widget with Directionality and set textDirection: TextDirection.rtl.

```
child: Directionality(
          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
          child: ExpansionTile(
            leading: ImageContainer(imageAddress: imageAddress),
            title: const Text(
              volleyballChampions,
              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            ),
            subtitle: const Text(
              testDateText,
              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            ),
            trailing: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                // TODO: develop dropdown container
              },
              child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/arrow_down.svg"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```