# Keep Flutter app layout LTR but using RTL language

Tags: flutter, macos

I have a blog app, I need to keep the layout of my app in LTR (because i like the app in English style) but I need to make the language of my posts in RTL only.

How to make the full app using RTL style for posts?

Comment: may link usefult.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50535185/right-to-left-rtl-in-flutter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [right-to-left (RTL) in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50535185/right-to-left-rtl-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force LTR directionality even when the language is RTL, you can wrap your whole widget tree under `MaterialApp` using `Directionality` widget. Try this:

```
MaterialApp(
  ...
  builder: (context, child) {
    return Directionality(textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, child: child!);
  },
);
```