# SearchDelegate text direction

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-search-delegate

how to change text direction to **RTL** in SearchDelegate

From the research, I found a way to change the color, but I did not find a way to change the direction of the text

thanks

```js
class MySearchDelegte extends SearchDelegate {

  @override
  String get searchFieldLabel => 'ابحث حسب اسم المكتب';
  .....
  .....

  @override
  ThemeData appBarTheme(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme.of(context).copyWith(
      appBarTheme: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.copyWith(
            color: const Color(0xff202c3b),

          ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [right-to-left (RTL) in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50535185/right-to-left-rtl-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the entire `SearchDelegate` widget in a `Directionality` widget and set the `textDirection` property to `TextDirection.rtl`.

```
Directionality(
  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
  child: MySearchDelegate(),
)
```

You can also set this property on an ancestor MaterialApp , which will propagate the text direction to all descendant widgets.

```
aterialApp(
  home: MySearchDelegate(),
  localizationsDelegates: [
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
  supportedLocales: [
    const Locale('ar', 'AE'), // Arabic
  ],
  locale: const Locale('ar', 'AE'),
)
```

---

Find more information in official flutter documentation

- [Directionality class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Directionality-class.html)
- [Globalization and Accessibility](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization)

Comment: Thank you, but we can't warp SearchDelegate with any other widget
And I tried to warp the scaffold with text direction, but it didn't work either