# emoji input changing it's position after printing the value from text Field

Tags: flutter

```
  TextEditingController? textFieldKeywordsController;
  Widget textFieldKeywords(){
    return TextField(
      controller: textFieldKeywordsController,
      cursorColor: Colors.white,
      onChanged: (str){
        print(str);
      },
    );
  }
```

my issue related to the emoji input

example :
**language `LTR :`**

when user starting to write **"Hello world "**

value on `textField` looks like: `"Hello world "` // as expected

printed value looks like  : `"Hello world "` // as expected

**language `RTL:`** **Arabic**

when user starting to write **" مرحبا يا عالم"**

value on `textField` looks like: `" مرحبا يا عالم"` // as expected

printed value looks like : `"مرحبا يا عالم ""` // emoji changed its position

the emoji changed its position . How to print it exactly like the value on text field  .

not only on the console , the emoji also changing its position to any preview widget like Text Widget specially in chat page

How to fix . thanks

Comment: I believe the issue is with the `print` function itself. It treats the given text as LTR

Comment: No at all  .... ....

Comment: So the `TextField` correctly treats the input as RTL, but the `print` function prints it to the console as LTR. That makes the arabic text comes first, after that the space and the emoji is treated as regular LTR text, that's why it appears to the right of the arabic text

Comment: agree , This causes me some embarrassment in the text messages in the chat between users too , not only print function

Comment: Probably better to update the question to focus on the widget affected, so the answer will directly solve that problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [right-to-left (RTL) in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50535185/right-to-left-rtl-in-flutter)

Comment: In general, you should make the whole app RTL, not just the `TextField`. Follow the instructions on the link above. This post may get marked as duplicate but I think it's a good [signpost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) for future readers.

Comment: thank you for this link , so do you think if i make the whole app RTL it will also effecting the languages that using LTR like new problem?

Comment: The problem happens because previously you have `TextField` as an RTL while the rest of the app is LTR. As long as the two are in sync, there should be no problem at all, whatever inputted to the `TextField` will appears the same in other widget